# Max in array and its frequency

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

How do you write a function that finds max value in an array as well as the number of times the value appears in the array?

We have to use recursion to solve this problem.

So far i am thinking it should be something like this:

```
int findMax(int[] a, int head, int last)
{
    int max = 0;

    if (head == last) {
        return a[head];
    }
    else if (a[head] < a[last]) {
        count ++;
        return findMax(a, head + 1, last);
    }
}
```

i am not sure if this will return the absolute highest value though, and im not exactly sure how to change what i have

Comment: What are your thoughts?  How would you use recursion to approach either of these pieces of information about an array?

Comment: To use recursion effectively, firstly you need to establish a base case that will get you out of recursion once the whole problem is solved. Secondly, you must find rule(s) that will get you from your first invocation of the recursive function towards progress solving the problem. Thirdly, combine the progress by invoking the function recursively, until you reach the base case in step one.

Comment: Break it down into two parts. First write a recursive function that finds the max value. Then add a way to keep track of how many times it occurred.

Comment: @user3112926  Offer a modification.  "establish a base case that will get you out of recursion once the whole problem is solved" should be more like "establish a base case that will get you out of recursion once the _sub-problem is simply solved_".  To return only when the whole problem is solved invites N depth recursive calls.  By returning when a sub-problem is solved, the recursive depth can be much smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the initial value of `max` to `INT_MIN` solves a number of issues. @Rerito

But the approach OP uses iterates through each member of the array and incurs a recursive call for each element.  So if the array had 1000 `int` there would be about 1000 nested calls.

A divide and conquer approach:

If the array length is 0 or 1, handle it. Else find the max answer from the 1st and second halves.  Combine the results as appropriate.  By dividing by 2, the stack depth usage for a 1000 element array will not exceed 10 nested calls.

Note: In either approach, the number of calls is the same.  The difference lies in the maximum degree of nesting.  Using recursion where a simple `for()` loop would suffice is questionable.  To conquer a more complex assessment is recursion's strength, hence this approach.

---

To find the max and its frequency using O(log2(length)) stack depth usage:

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
  int value;
  size_t frequency;  // `size_t` better to use that `int` for large arrays.
} value_freq;

value_freq findMax(const int *a, size_t length) {
  value_freq vf;

  if (length <= 1) {
    if (length == 0) {
      vf.value = INT_MIN;  // Degenerate value if the array was size 0.
      vf.frequency = 0;
    } else {
      vf.value = *a;
      vf.frequency = 1;
    }
  } else {
    size_t length1sthalf = length / 2;
    vf = findMax(a, length1sthalf);
    value_freq vf1 = findMax(&a[length1sthalf], length - length1sthalf);
    if (vf1.value > vf.value)
      return vf1;
    if (vf.value == vf1.value)
      vf.frequency += vf1.frequency;
  }
  return vf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not thaaaat far.

In order to save the frequency and the max you can keep a pointer to a structure, then just pass the pointer to the start of your array, the length you want to go through, and a pointer to this struct.
Keep in mind that you should use `INT_MIN` in `limits.h` as your initial max (see `reset(maxfreq *)` in the code below), as `int` can carry negative values.

The following code does the job recursively:

```
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {
    int max;
    int freq;
} maxfreq;

void reset(maxfreq *mfreq){
    mfreq->max = INT_MIN;
    mfreq->freq = 0;
}

void findMax(int* a, int length, maxfreq *mfreq){

    if(length>0){
        if(*a == mfreq->max)
            mfreq->freq++;
        else if(*a > mfreq->max){
            mfreq->freq = 1;
            mfreq->max = *a;
        }

        findMax(a+1, length - 1, mfreq);
    }
}
```

A call to `findMax` will recall itself as many times as the initial length plus one, each time incrementing the provided pointer and processing the corresponding element, so this is basically just going through all of the elements in `a` once, and no weird splitting.

Comment: Of course, the initial minimum could be set as the first value in the array too...

Comment: Well, that would screw up the frequency count, wouldn't it?

Comment: Also, that would imply modifying/copying the passed array, and doing an extra pass. Plus, I know this is a C question, but that `reset` function would do for a nice maxfreq constructor in C++ :)

Comment: Although this uses recursion, it uses O(length) stack depth.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine with me :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// define a struct that contains the (max, freq) information
struct arrInfo
{
    int max;
    int count;
};

struct arrInfo maxArr(int * arr, int max, int size, int count)
{

    int maxF;
    struct arrInfo myArr;

    if(size == 0)   // to return from recursion we check the size left
    {
        myArr.max = max;    // prepare the struct to output
        myArr.count = count;
        return(myArr);
    }

    if(*arr > max)   // new maximum found
    {
        maxF = *arr;  // update the max
        count = 1;    // initialize the frequency
    }
    else if (*arr == max) // same max encountered another time
    {
        maxF = max;     // keep track of same max
        count ++;       // increase frequency
    }
    else             // nothing changes
        maxF = max;  // keep track of max


    arr++;      // move the pointer to next element
    size --;    // decrease size by 1

    return(maxArr(arr, maxF, size, count)); // recursion

}

int main()
{
    struct arrInfo info; // return of the recursive function

    // define an array
    int arr[] = {8, 4, 8, 3, 7};

    info = maxArr(arr, 0, 5, 1); // call with max=0 size=5 freq=1


    printf("max = %d  count = %d\n", info.max, info.count);
    return 0;
}
```

when ran, it outputs :

```
max = 8  count = 3
```

**Notice**
In my code example I assumed the numbers to be positive (initializing `max` to `0`), I don't know your requirements but you can elaborate.

Comment: Just initialize max to `INT_MIN` (defined in limits.h) and this avoids any problem with negative ints :)

Comment: Initializing with `freq=1` is a problem should  the initial `max` value end up as the maximum.  The results is off-by-1.  Better to initialize with `freq=0`.

Comment: @chux: you r right for extreme safe `freq` is better initialized to `0`, But it would be really non-sense act if the user calls the function with `initial max` as the `real max` ! but I admit your suggestion in all cases

Answer (score 0):

The reqirements in your assignment are at least questionable. Just for reference, here is how this should be done in real code (to solve your assignment, refer to the other answers):

```
int findMax(int length, int* array, int* maxCount) {
    int trash;
    if(!maxCount) maxCount = &trash;    //make sure we ignore it when a NULL pointer is passed in

    *maxCount = 0;
    int result = INT_MIN;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(array[i] > result) {
            *maxCount = 1;
            result = array[i];
        } else if(array[i] == result) {
            (*maxCount)++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Always do things as straight forward as you can.

Comment: @chouaib It's not supposed to be there. Using recursion does not conform to KISS in this case, and I explicitly said that this is not the solution to the assignment of the OP.